Why is my Angular signal effect not firing?
The class below declares a signal and an update function for the signal:
export class ProductSidebarService {
  public productSidebarSignal = signal<{
    productSidebarData: ProductSidebarData;
  }>({ productSidebarData: new ProductSidebarData() });

  public updateSidebarData = (productSidebarData: ProductSidebarData) => {
    this.productSidebarSignal.set({productSidebarData:{... productSidebarData} });
    console.dir('ProductSidebarService.productSidebarSignal', this.productSidebarSignal())
  };
}

The class below declares an effect that is supposed to fire when the above signal is updated but the effect never fires:
export class ProductGalleryComponent {
  private productSidebarService = inject(ProductSidebarService);
  public productSidebarData = this.productSidebarService.productSidebarSignal();

  private productSidebarEffect = effect(() => {    
    console.dir('ProductGalleryComponent.productSidebarSignal', this.productSidebarService.productSidebarSignal())


  });
}


The problem might be console.dir, which does not show the output of the signal  when passed in with comma separated values, apart from that from the data provided, the effect is firing.
Also make sure, you have console.log set on when you update the signal and when you initialize the effect, you can set a console.log on the constructor of ProductGalleryComponent if the component is initialized after the signal is set, the effect might fire only once.
Also note, that signal updates are kind of debounced, so it will fire only once.
import { Component, inject, Injectable, signal, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpParams,
  provideHttpClient,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';

export class ProductSidebarData {
  constructor(public test: string = '') {}
}
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService {
  public productSidebarSignal = signal<{
    productSidebarData: ProductSidebarData;
  }>({ productSidebarData: new ProductSidebarData() });

  public updateSidebarData = (productSidebarData: ProductSidebarData) => {
    this.productSidebarSignal.set({
      productSidebarData: { ...productSidebarData },
    });
    console.log(
      'ProductSidebarService.productSidebarSignal',
      this.productSidebarSignal()
    );
  };
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `asdf`,
})
export class App {
  productSidebarService = inject(SomeService);

  private productSidebarEffect = effect(() => {
    console.log(
      'ProductGalleryComponent.productSidebarSignal',
      this.productSidebarService.productSidebarSignal()
    );
  });
  constructor() {
    console.log('test');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('storing');
    this.productSidebarService.updateSidebarData(
      new ProductSidebarData('qwerty')
    );
    this.productSidebarService.updateSidebarData(
      new ProductSidebarData('qwerty1')
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
});

Stackblitz Demo

I have changed every console.dir in the application to console.log but the problem persists. The effect is not triggering.

@koque could you try my suggestions maybe the signal is updated before the effect is initialized

Issues
Effect Not Reacting: The effect in ProductGalleryComponent should directly reference the signal to react to changes.
Initialization: Avoid capturing the initial state of the signal.
the typescript code:-
import { effect, inject } from 'some-reactive-library'; // Adjust import based on your context

export class ProductGalleryComponent {
  private productSidebarService = inject(ProductSidebarService);

  constructor() {
    // Set up the effect to react to changes in the signal
    effect(() => {
      const currentSidebarData = this.productSidebarService.productSidebarSignal();
      console.dir('ProductGalleryComponent.productSidebarSignal', currentSidebarData);
    });
  }
}

whereas, the debug console:-
Ensure 'updateSidebarData' is called with new data:
public updateSidebarData = (productSidebarData: ProductSidebarData) => {
  console.dir('Updating sidebar data', productSidebarData);
  this.productSidebarSignal.set({ productSidebarData: { ...productSidebarData } });
  console.dir('ProductSidebarService.productSidebarSignal', this.productSidebarSignal());
};

Hope embedding this changes its directly referencing the signal in the effect and ensuring updates change the state, the effect should fire correctly.
